# How to refresh gridviews and dynamically show one at a time based on type selection?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, grid

I have two gridviews in my page and a type selection dropdownlist with type1 to type 6 listitems in it.

If user selects type1 to type4, then gridview1 should be displayed and if type5 to type6 selected, gridview2 should be displayed and accordingly either one of the two gridviews should be displayed at a time.

Now, for each type selection, gridviews are bound with data.

Now for each selection, I want the grid to be refreshed and show latest data in it...

How to do this....

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have Type1 to Type4 in first for locations of dropdown and remaining two types are after these.

**In HTML side**

```
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSel" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlSel_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

**In Code Behind**

```
protected void ddlSel_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
  if(ddlSel.SelectedIndex < 4)
  {
     gridView1.DataSource = dt1; //This could be call to method returning datatable for gridview1
     gridView1.DataBind();
     gridView1.Visible = true;
     gridView2.Visible = false;
  }
  else
  {
     gridView2.DataSource = dt2; //This could be call to method returning datatable for gridview2
     gridView2.DataBind();
     gridView2.Visible = true;
     gridView1.Visible = false;    
  }    
}
```